# Taking two inputs as initial and final value and printing range

Tags: python, string

This is my code:

```
a,b=input().split()
for x in range(a,b):
print(list(x))
```

Why is this not working?

It says can't interpret `str` as an `int`.

And when I put it under `int()`, it says `int()` argument must be a string.

I want this:

Input:

```
2 6
```

Output:

```
3

4

5

6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does exactly what you expect:

```
a,b=input().split()
for x in range(int(a)+1,int(b)+1):
    print(x)
```

`input()` returns a string, and `split()` returns a list of strings. You have to convert them to integers before feeding them to `range`. Also, in `print(x)` `x` is already a number and there is no reason to convert it into a list (and it would not work, either).

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `print(list(x))` with `print(x)` . I don't see any reason to use  `list()` . You can also use `range(a,b+1)` instead of `range(a,b)` if you want the last number printed to be the same as `b`.

Comment: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Answer (score 0):

By default, `input()` accepts values as string and `split()` returns a list of strings. You need to convert `a` and `b` to int after input. Also, you need to get rid of `list(x)` and just `print(x)` since `int` in Python is not iterable.
The correct code is:

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
for x in range(a + 1, b + 1):
    print(x)
```

OR

```
a, b = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for x in range(a + 1, b + 1):
    print(x)
```

In both cases, for input `2 6`, the output is

```
3
4
5
6
```